# Get values which only occur in one of two flat arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have following two arrays.  I want the difference between these two arrays. That is, how can I find the values that do not exist in both arrays?

```
 $array1 = [64, 98, 112, 92, 92, 92];
 $array2 = [3, 26, 38, 40, 44, 46, 48, 52, 64, 68, 70, 72, 102, 104, 106, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 108, 110, 112];
```

Comment: This question doesn't have an explicit declaration of the desired result.  I think the example could be a more _minimal_ [mcve].

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Note:** this answer will return the values in `$array2` that are not present in `$array1`, it will not return the values in `$array1` that are not in `$array2`.

```
$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

[`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array-diff)

Comment: This appears to be incorrect - it won't return values from `$array2` that don't exist in `$array1`. [Crasherspeeder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays/10077920#10077920) seems to have it right.

Comment: @Crasherspeeder is correct, this is a one directional check - asker wants both.

Comment: array_diff_* family also throws "ErrorException: Array to string conversion" for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: i'm encountering troubles with this aray_diff(), but probably i was expecting something wrong. Just for some kind of test i cloned an array and modified one value. i'll expect "the same result" if i do array_diff(array1,array2) and array_diff(arra2,array1), with the difference of the value showed, but i'll have: array(1) { ["key_modified"]=> string(1) "0" } AND array(0) { }. why?

Answer (score 204):

To get the difference between the two arrays you need to do the following:

```
$fullDiff = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

The reason being that `array_diff()` will only give you the values that are in `$array1` but not `$array2`, not the other way around.  The above will give you both.

Comment: If you need to maintain keys: `$full_diff = array_diff($array1, $array2) + array_diff($array2, $array1);`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get the differences between arrays recursively, try this function:

```
function arrayDiffRecursive(array $firstArray,array  $secondArray, bool $reverse = false): array 
{
    $first = 'first';
    $second = 'second';
    if ($reverse) {
        $first = 'second';
        $second = 'first';
    }
    $diff = [];
    foreach ($firstArray as $k => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            if (!array_key_exists($k, $secondArray) || $secondArray[$k] != $value) {
                $diff[$first][$k] = $value;
                $diff[$second][$k] = $secondArray[$k] ?? null;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($k, $secondArray) || !is_array($secondArray[$k])) {
            $diff[$first][$k] = $value;
            $diff[$second][$k] = $secondArray[$k] ?? null;
            continue;
        }
        $newDiff = arrayDiffRecursive($value, $secondArray[$k], $reverse);
        if (!empty($newDiff)) {
            $diff[$first][$k] = $newDiff[$first];
            $diff[$second][$k] = $newDiff[$second];
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

Test:

```
$firstArray = ['a' => ['b' => 'c'], 'g' => ['h' => 's']];
$secondArray = ['b' => 'c', 'd' => ['e' => 'f'], 'g' => ['i' => 'j']];
$diffs = array_replace_recursive(
    arrayDiffRecursive($firstArray, $secondArray),
    arrayDiffRecursive($secondArray, $firstArray, true)
);
print_r($diffs);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [b] => c
                )

            [g] => Array
                (
                    [h] => s
                    [i] =>
                )

            [b] =>
            [d] =>
        )

    [second] => Array
        (
            [a] =>
            [g] => Array
                (
                    [h] =>
                    [i] => j
                )

            [b] => c
            [d] => Array
                (
                    [e] => f
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function getArrayDiff($a1, $a2) {
    $result = array();

    print_r($a1);
    print_r($a2);

    // If First Array is Bigger than Second
    if( count($a1) > count($a2) ) {
        $result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
    }
    // If Second Array is Bigger than First
    if( count($a1) < count($a2) ) {
        $result=array_diff($a2,$a1);
    }
    // If Both array are same but, data values are different.
    else
    {
        $result = array_merge (array_diff($a2,$a1), array_diff($a1,$a2));   
    }
    return $result;
}

print "<pre>";
// First Array is Big
echo "First Array is Big <br/>";
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");
print_r( getArrayDiff($a1, $a2) );

// Second Array is Big
echo "Second Array is Big <br/>";
$a1=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");
$a2=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
print_r( getArrayDiff($a1, $a2) );

// Both Array are same
echo "Both Array are same <br/>";
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");
print_r( getArrayDiff($a1, $a2) );

?>
```

> Output:

```
First Array is Big 
Array
(
    [a] => red
    [b] => green
    [c] => blue
    [d] => yellow
)
Array
(
    [e] => red
    [f] => green
    [g] => blue
)
Array
(
    [d] => yellow
)
Second Array is Big 
Array
(
    [e] => red
    [f] => green
    [g] => blue
)
Array
(
    [a] => red
    [b] => green
    [c] => blue
    [d] => yellow
)
Array
(
    [d] => yellow
)
Both Array are same 
Array
(
    [a] => red
    [b] => green
    [d] => yellow
)
Array
(
    [e] => red
    [f] => green
    [g] => blue
)
Array
(
    [g] => blue
    [d] => yellow
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `array_diff()`.
Something to keep it mind is that the order in which the argument is written.

PHP Doc: [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```php
# array_diff(1, 2)
array_diff($one, $two);

# array_diff(2, 1)
array_diff($two, $one); // produces different result.
```

Answer (score 1):

array_diff?

http://php.net/array_diff

```
var_dump(array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = range(000000, 999999);
$numbers = array_map(function ($n) {
    if (strlen($n) < 6) {
        $addZero = 6 - strlen($n);
        $appendZero = str_repeat('0', $addZero);
        $n = $appendZero . $n;
    }
    return $n;
}, $numbers);
$allRanges = array_diff($numbers, $getAllPurchasedTicketsArr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.