# PHP compare arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have two arrays. `$arrayOld` and `$arrayNew` and I want to compare these arrays and only select the values that are not in `$arrayNew`.

I don't want the values that are in `$arrayNew` only. So I don't think `array_diff()` is gonna help me.

```
$arrayOld = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
$arrayNew = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

So it only needs to return `2` and `3` and not `6` or `7`.

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff)?

Comment: Use `array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew)`

Comment: array_diff() will give me 6 and 7 also right?

Comment: check https://3v4l.org/flAGU

Comment: @WouterdenOuden, Nope!! Array diff only returns from the first array which is not in second array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `array_diff`, to accomplish this. As you need to difference between the array and need data from Old array so you need to use the old array as the first parameter of the array_diff.

> **Note:** Array diff only returns from the first array which is not in second array.

```
$arrayOld = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$arrayNew = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7];

$n = array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew);

print_r($n);
```

**Result:** [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/tdb3t)

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

If you need a new keys for the output array just use `array_values`. The new key start from 0.

```
$arr = array_values($n);
```

Comment: 6 and 7 should not come in results, check question again

Comment: @WouterdenOuden, Array diff only returns from the first array which is not in second array.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
$arrayOld = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$arrayNew = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7];
print "<pre>";
print_r(array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Ohw you're right. I thought it will give all the different values from both arrays

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
$arrayOld = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arrayNew = array(1, 4, 5, 6, 7);

print_r(array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew));

$compare = array();
$i=1;
foreach($arrayOld as $k=>$v){
    if(!in_array($v, $arrayNew)){
        $compare[$i] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
}

$i=$i;
foreach($arrayNew as $k=>$v){
    if(!in_array($v, $arrayOld)){
        $compare[$i] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `array_diff` function

```
$arrayOld = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arrayNew = array(1, 4, 5, 6, 7);

print_r(array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew));
```