# compare two json array and remove duplicates in PHP

Tags: php, json

#### here i want compare two json array and remove duplicates.

```
 $jsonArray1 = '["7.00 am To 8.00 am","1.00 pm To 2.00 pm","2.00 pm To 3.00 pm"]';
    $jsonArray2 = '["7.00 am To 8.00 am","1.00 pm To 2.00 pm","2.00 pm To 3.00 pm","10.00 am To 11.00 am"]';
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: just remove duplicate and show original data.

Comment: post that *original data*

Comment: "10.00 am To 11.00 am"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)  ...specifically see the selected answer: exact duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_intersect` and `array_filter` functions:

```
$json_str1 = '["7.00 am To 8.00 am","1.00 pm To 2.00 pm","2.00 pm To 3.00 pm"]';
$json_str2 = '["7.00 am To 8.00 am","1.00 pm To 2.00 pm","2.00 pm To 3.00 pm","10.00 am To 11.00 am"]';

list($arr1, $arr2) = [json_decode($json_str1), json_decode($json_str2)];
$common_items = array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);
$result = array_filter(array_merge($arr1, $arr2), function($v) use($common_items){
    return !in_array($v, $common_items);
});

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [6] => 10.00 am To 11.00 am
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert json string to array using json_decode
   and USE array_diff to find different value

Here's the code -

```
   $arr1 = json_decode($jsonArray1); 
   $arr2 = json_decode($jsonArray2); 

   $newarr = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
   print_r($newarr);  // php array format
   json_encode($newarr); // json format
```

Comment: but your's 
Array ( [0] => 7.00 am To 8.00 am [1] => 1.00 pm To 2.00 pm [2] => 2.00 pm To 3.00 pm [6] => 10.00 am To 11.00 am ) like that

Comment: oh got it so you want to remove duplicate data too ..sorry mate ...i missed that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//you have to decode arrays
$json1 = json_decode( $jsonArray1, true);
$json2 = json_decode( $jsonArray2, true);

//find duplicates
$find_duplicates = array_intersect($json1, $json2);

//remove duplicates from first array 
$json1 = array_diff($json1, $find_duplicates);

///remove duplicates from second array 
$json2 = array_diff($json2, $find_duplicates);
```

Comment: $out = array_values($json2);
    $arry_merge = (array_merge($json1,$json2));

    echo json_encode($arry_merge).'--op';

Comment: finally i got @Mr Alb.