# Find removed and added items of modified array

Tags: php, arrays, diff

How to find what items are removed from last state array list and what items a add to new one? 
My arrays:

```
$arrayOld = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"];
$arrayNew = ["Z", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "Y"];
```

Explanation:
I have an array called `$arrayOld`, User do some modification on the list and post a new array to the server and i want to know what items are removed from first array and what items are new!

Thanks

Comment: You mean, compare the arrays ? You want to find which element is on old but not in new and vice versa ?

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Show us what you tried to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply find those using array_diff:

```php
$arrayOld = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"];
$arrayNew = ["Z", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "Y"];

$removes = array_diff($arrOld, $arrNew);
print_r($removes); // A , K

$adds = array_diff($arrNew,$arrOld);
print_r($adds); // Z , Y
```

As per php.net docs:

> array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

[php.function.array-diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

array_diff would be a solution,

Get adds,

```
 $new_elements = array_diff($arrayNew, $arrayOld);
    print_r($new_elements); // first parameter should be new array 
and second one should be old
```

Get Removals,

```
    $old_elements = array_diff($arrayOld, $arrayNew);
    print_r($old_elements); // Here first parameter should be old array 
and second one should be new
```

Answer (score 0):

use the diff function it will show all the different with the index of the change items

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"black","g"=>"purple");
$a3=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"black","h"=>"yellow");


$result=array_diff($a1,$a2,$a3);
print_r($result);
```

the result will be :

Array ( [b] => green [c] => blue );