# Remove duplicate values and get unique values from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays in two variables

In Variable one i have `Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c )`

And in variable two i have `Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b )`

I want unique value from both array, for example same values `111a` and `112b` should be remove and i need unique value **`113c`** in one variable.

Another example

In variable one i have `Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c )`

And in variable two i have `Array ( [0] => 111a )`

the same value 111a should be remove and i need 112b and 113c in one variable.

I searched on internet for that and tried `array_merge` and `array_unique`

```
$before_ser = Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c ) 

$after_ser = Array ( [0] => 111a )

$merge_ser = array_merge($before_ser, $after_ser);
```

I have below output in `$merge_ser`

```
Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c [3] => 111a ) 



$unique_ser=array_unique($merge_ser);
```

And i have below output in `$unique_ser`

```
Array ( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c )
```

But after all, i can not get the output that i want, is there any solution for that?

Comment: Try `array_diff` . Ex: https://eval.in/895910

Comment: @SahilGulati Its work... Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you friend.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably fit your needs:

`array_diff($array1,$array2)`

Edit: Sahil beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$before_ser = array( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b [2] => 113c )
$after_ser = array( [0] => 111a [1] => 112b);
$output = array_merge(array_diff($before_ser, $after_ser), array_diff($after_ser, $before_ser));
```