# How to exclude some elements from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array of domains and I would like to echo that array without some of them **and without** `array_diff`. Is this possible?

for example, I have this:

```
$all_domains_array = array('domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com');

$domains_2_exclude_array = array('domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
```

And I need to echo all domains from array `$all_domains_array` without the domains from array `$domains_2_exclude_array`

Comment: `print_r(array_diff($all_domains,$domains_2_exclude));` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i=0,$count = count($all_domains_array);$i<$count;$i++) {
  if (!in_array($all_domains_array[$i],$domains_2_exclude_array))
    echo $all_domains_array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function

```
$all_domains_array = array('domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
$domains_2_exclude_array = array('domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
$finalArray = array_diff($all_domains_array, $domains_2_exclude_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_diff() function. please see the below code, it may help you

```
$all_domains_array = array('domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com');

 $domains_2_exclude_array = array('domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
 $ss= array_diff($all_domains_array,$domains_2_exclude_array);
 print_r($ss);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$all_domains_array = array('domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
$domains_2_exclude_array = array('domain3.com', 'domain4.com');
$remain_array = array_diff($all_domains_array, $domains_2_exclude_array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($remain_array); 
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using an array function in PHP
*array_diff()*

example:

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");
$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [d] => yellow )
```

In your case simply do this:

```
$result = array_diff($all_domains_array,$domains_2_exclude_array)
```