# Find and output elements in array (1) not listed in array (2) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have the following:

`$Array1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);`

`$Array2(2, 1, 5, 8, 7);`

I would like to output using `echo` all the elements in `$Array1` that are not in `$Array2`. Note that elements in `$Array2`are not necessarily in sequential order.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here:

```
$array1 = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

$array2 = array(2, 1, 5, 8, 7);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
  if(!in_array($value,$array2)){
    echo $value. '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as key =>$value){
  if(!in_array($value,$array2)){
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. ```if(!in_array($value,$array2))``` works better.

Comment: yeah sorry mistakenly forget that. now updated